# Simple convolutional neural network

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
import time

# Functions

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0,x)

def relu_derivative(x):
    return np.greater(x, 0).astype(int)

def softmax(x):
    exps = np.exp(x - x.max())
    return exps / np.sum(exps)

# Import and Create Dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# Setup
np.random.seed(seed=12345)
alpha = 0.05

# Initialize Network Values

# Layers
input_layer = np.zeros(shape=(28,28))
convolutional_layer = np.zeros(shape=(10,24,24))
pooling_layer = np.zeros(shape=(10,12,12))
flattened_layer = np.reshape(pooling_layer,newshape=(1440,1))
dense_layer = np.zeros(shape=(100,1))
output_layer = np.zeros(shape=(10,1))

# Filters and Weights
convolution_filters = np.random.rand(10,5,5)
weights1 = np.random.rand(100,1440)
weights2 = np.random.rand(10,100)

# Bias
dense_layer_bias = np.ones(shape=(100,1))
output_layer_bias = np.ones(shape=(10,1))
convolution_bias = np.ones(shape=(10,5,5))

for epoch in range(1):
    print(np.mean(weights1),np.mean(weights2),np.mean(convolution_filters))
    for sample in range(20):
        # Get Input Data
        input = x_train[sample]
        # Target Data
        target = np.zeros((10,1))
        target[y_train[sample]][0] = 1
        # Feed Forward Input to Convolution Layer
        i=j=k=0
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(24):
                for k in range(24):
                    minimatrix = input[j:j+5, k:k+5]
                    convolutional_layer[i][j][k] = np.sum(minimatrix * convolution_filters[i] + convolution_bias[i]) 
        # Pooling Layer
        i=j=k=0
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(12):
                for k in range(12):
                    minimatrix = convolutional_layer[i,j*2:j*2+2,k*2:k*2+2]
                    pooling_layer[i][j][k] = relu(minimatrix.max())
        # Flattening Layer
        flattened_layer = np.reshape(pooling_layer,newshape=(1440,1))
        # Feed Forward - DENSE_LAYER
        dense_layer = relu(np.dot(weights1,flattened_layer) + dense_layer_bias)
        # Feed Forward - OUTPUT_LAYER
        output_layer = softmax(np.dot(weights2,dense_layer) + output_layer_bias)
        
        # Backpropogation - OUTPUT_LAYER
        delta = output_layer - target
        weights2gradient = np.dot(delta,dense_layer.T)
        output_layer_bias_gradient = delta

        # Backpropogation - DENSE_LAYER
        delta = np.dot(weights2.T,delta) * relu_derivative(dense_layer)
        weights1gradient = np.dot(delta,flattened_layer.T)
        dense_layer_bias_gradient = delta

        # Backpropogation - POOLING_LAYER
        delta = np.reshape(np.dot(weights1.T,delta),newshape=(10,12,12)) * relu_derivative(pooling_layer) # find delta at pooling layer
        
        # Backpropagation - TRANSPOSE FOR CALCULATIONS
        delta = np.array([delta[i].T for i in range(len(delta))]) # Math says this has to happen

        # Gradient For Backward Pass
        pooling_backward_pass = np.zeros(shape=(10,24,24)) # matrix for passing adjusted cost

        # BACKWARD POOLING GRADIENT PASS
        i=j=k=0
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(12):
                for k in range(12):
                    minimatrix = convolutional_layer[i,j*2:j*2+2,k*2:k*2+2]
                    maxvalindex = np.argmax(minimatrix)
                    pooling_backward_pass[i, j*2+(maxvalindex // 2), k+(maxvalindex % 2)] += delta[i,j,k]
        
        # Backpropogation - CONVOLUTION LAYER
        convolution_gradient = np.zeros(shape=(10,5,5))
        convolution_bias_gradient = np.zeros(shape=(10,5,5))
        i=j=k=0
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(24):
                for k in range(24):
                    minimatrix = input[j:j+5, k:k+5]
                    convolution_gradient[i] += pooling_backward_pass[i,j,k] * minimatrix
                    convolution_bias_gradient[i] += pooling_backward_pass[i,j,k]
        
        # Weight and Filter Adjustments
        weights2 -= weights2gradient * alpha
        weights1 -= weights1gradient * alpha
        convolution_filters -= convolution_gradient * alpha
        # Bias Adjustments
        dense_layer_bias -= dense_layer_bias_gradient * alpha
        output_layer_bias -= output_layer_bias_gradient * alpha
        convolution_bias -= convolution_gradient * alpha
print(np.mean(weights1),np.mean(weights2),np.mean(convolution_filters))
```

I have been working on this code for a while now and I am (almost) certain the basic functionality should work, but I am getting no changes to the weights of the network. I am specifically trying to understand neural networks without the abstraction offered by the actual frameworks. Is there a Python scope issue that is keeping the weights from updating?

Comment: Which variables exactly did you expect to be updated with which values, and which values do they have instead? What did you find when you tried to debug this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am trying to find why the weights update on the first pass (sample 1) and then do not change (I am testing this by taking the average since the matrices are so large). The cost derivative is changing ever so slightly but the weights1,weights2, the convolution weights are changing. I have been backtracking and the flattened layer is becoming zeros after the first pass. Is ReLU not the correct activation the result of convolution?

Comment: Maybe your learning rate is too low. I doubt it but it's still probably worth seeing if there is any change for different values of lr.